# array values in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays

they look like

```
$a1 = array(
  array('num' => 1, 'name' => 'one'),
  array('num' => 2, 'name' => 'two'),
  array('num' => 3, 'name' => 'three'),
  array('num' => 4, 'name' => 'four'),
  array('num' => 5, 'name' => 'five')
)

$a2 = array(3,4,5,6,7,8);
```

I want to end up with an array that looks like

```
$a3 = array(3,4,5);
```

so basically where `$a1[$i]['num']` is in `$a2`

I know I could do

```
$a3 = array();

foreach($a1 as $num)
 if(array_search($num['num'], $a2))
   $a3[] = $num['num'];
```

But that seems like a lot of un-needed iterations.

Is there a better way?

---

**Ah Snap...**
I just realized I asked this question the wrong way around, I want to end up with an array that looks like

```
$a3 array(
  array('num' => 3, 'name' => 'three'),
  array('num' => 4, 'name' => 'four'),
  array('num' => 5, 'name' => 'five')
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could extract the relevant informations *(the `'num'` items)* from `$a1` :

```
$a1_bis = array();
foreach ($a1 as $a) {
    $a1_bis[] = $a['num'];
}
```

And, then, use [**`array_intersect()`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) to find what is both in `$a1_bis` and `$a2` :

```
$result = array_intersect($a1_bis, $a2);
var_dump($result);
```

Which would get you :

```
array
  2 => int 3
  3 => int 4
  4 => int 5
```

With this solution :

- you are going through `$a1` only once
- you trust PHP on using a good algorithm to find the intersection between the two arrays *(and/or consider that a function developed in C will probably be faster than any equivalent you could code in pure-PHP)*

---

**EDIT after the comment :** well, considering the result you want, now, I would go with another approach.

First, I would use [**`array_flip()`**](http://fr.php.net/array_flip) to *flip* the `$a2` array, to allow faster access to its elements *(accessing by key is way faster than finding a value)* :

```
$a2_hash = array_flip($a2); // To speed things up : 
                            // accessing by key is way faster than finding 
                            // an item in an array by value
```

Then, I would use [**`array_filter()`**](http://fr.php.net/array_filter) to apply a filter to `$a1`, keeping the items for which `num` is in the `$a2_hash` flipped-array :

```
$result = array_filter($a1, function ($item) use ($a2_hash) {
    if (isset($a2_hash[ $item['num'] ])) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
var_dump($result);
```

*Note : I used an anonymous function, which only exist with PHP >= 5.3 ; if you are using PHP < 5.3, this code can be re-worked to suppress the closure.*

With that, I get the array you want :

```
array
  2 => 
    array
      'num' => int 3
      'name' => string 'three' (length=5)
  3 => 
    array
      'num' => int 4
      'name' => string 'four' (length=4)
  4 => 
    array
      'num' => int 5
      'name' => string 'five' (length=4)
```

Note the keys are not corresponding to anything useful -- if you want them *removed*, just use the [**`array_values()`**](http://fr.php.net/array_values) function on that `$result` :

```
$final_result = array_values($result);
```

But that's probably not necessary :-)

Comment: Hi Pascal, Thanks for this, can you please review my edit *facepalm*

Comment: @Hailwook I've edited my answer, with another approach, that makes things easier, considering the result you want :-)